# How can I get int value from Firebase and retrieve into variable Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[image]**I want to retrieve int data from Firebase and want to make bar chart using that value(UserData --> uid --> absCal)**

```
static List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createSampleData() {
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

// want to retrieve int value from firebase here....
//like...
//var a = FirebaseFirestore.instance......(like this)

final data = [
  OrdinalSales('abs', /* and want to put var here*/),
  OrdinalSales('shoulder', 25),
  OrdinalSales('chest', 10),
  OrdinalSales('back', 50),
];
```

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for flutter and firebase](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview) ? Take a look at [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read)

Comment: Try parsing the variable e.g. int.tryParse(varname)

Comment: @VinamraJaiswal i want int value from firebase. that i need in my code . basically i try to make dynamic chart so i want to retrieve int value in data[]. please look the image that i uploaded recently.

Comment: The documentation for Firebase+Flutter is pretty extensive and there are also quite some great tutorials out there. Unless you've already read those, tried to get them to work on your own, and got stuck somewhere more concretely, it is unlikely that we can explain things better here than those resources already do.

Comment: Please post minimal reproducible code with error details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Frank van Puffelen, There are various resources available on the Firebase+Flutter which can help you out in resolving this issue as following:
You can refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/) on how to use Firebase in Flutter and [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read) for reading data from  collections.
You can also watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bper2K92bd8) on getting data from the Firebase in Flutter.